# What’s the correct way to build the SQLite FTS extension as a DLL?

Tags: c, windows, sqlite, dll, full-text-search

What’s the recommended way to build the SQLite [FTS3 extension](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html) as a Windows DLL?

I’m having the following problem:

> fts3_tokenizer.obj : error LNK2005: sqlite3_api already defined in fts3.obj

The macro `SQLITE_EXTENSION_INIT1` is used in both `fts3_tokenizer.c` and `fts3.c`. It  creates a global variable named `sqlite3_api`, and since this is done in two places, there are two global variables of the same name. Hence the problem.

Note: Although FTS can be compiled into SQLite, I would like a DLL so I can dynamically load the extension into environments where I have a pre-compiled SQLite that doesn’t have full text search.

Answer (score 2):

Main instructions:
http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/09/23/compiling-sqlite-on-windows/

But use these preprocessor definitions:

SQLITE_ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA

SQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3

SQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3_PARENTHESIS

SQLITE_ENABLE_RTREE

ignore int / i64 and float/double warnings